# proof of injection, surjection and bijection of identity functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose there are two functions $$ f: X \to Y $$ and $$ g: Y \to X$$ and $ g \circ f = id_{X}$

Proof or disproof the following:

a) f is injectiv  
b) f is surjectiv 
c) g is injective 
d) g is surjective 
e) $f\circ g = id_{Y}$

After some research i was able to do a and b myself, however i stuck on c and d because in my head we can just use the answers from a and b and change the domain and codomain and some symbols to get the answers, basically should be the same as a and b. But i thought if it were that easy why would the professor give us the questions to do....So could someone tell me how to proceed or if there is a trick at all? Would be really great if you could give me one example proof of c and d so that i can check whether my answers are correct!!

NEW EDIT: I just found some older posts with similar questions where people said f is injective and g is surjective...i thought they were both bijective???? completely confused,,,would really appreciate some help clearing this thing.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should share what  you did in part a) and b) , then based on that you can proceed with other parts.

Comment: Do you mean you could do 1 and 3? Because if you got the correct answer for 1 and 2, then the other two should follow the same lines. Please show what you have done.

Comment: Guys i think my answers were wrong,,,,because i found old posts with the exact same function and people answered f would be injective and g would be surjectiv. however my answeres show they are both bijective....could you quickly help me with that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is true since if $f(x_1 ) =f(x_2 )$ for some $x_1 , x_2 \in X $ then $$x_1 = (g\circ f) (x_1 ) = (g\circ f) (x_2 ) =x_2$$
b) need not to be true, to see this take $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} , f(x) =x $ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{N}, g(x)=|\lfloor x\rfloor |$ then $$(g\circ f ) (n) =g(n)=|\lfloor n\rfloor |=n =\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{N}} (n)$$
but obviously $g$ is not surjective.

c) need not to be true, look at b).

d) is true, to see this take any $x\in X$ and let $y=f(x) $ then $$g(y) =g(f(x)) =(g\circ f)(x) =x$$ so $g$ is surjective.

e) need not to be true, to see this take $f,g$ from c) then $$(f\circ g)(y)= f(g(y)) =|\lfloor y\rfloor |\neq id_{\mathbb{R}} (y)$$